# jsPDF cannot set font family

Tags: javascript, fonts, jspdf

I cannot change the font family. This is directly off jsPDF [website](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf#):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'This is the default font.');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is courier normal.');

doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("italic");
doc.text(20, 40, 'This is times italic.');

doc.setFont("helvetica");
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(20, 50, 'This is helvetica bold.');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("bolditalic");
doc.text(20, 60, 'This is courier bolditalic.');
```

But here is what is printed for:

[image]

These are all just `times` font. Why is the font family not changing?

Comment: Which OS? Because I'm pretty sure those are not real font names. At the very least, they're "Courier", "Helvetica" and "Times" (casing matters)

Comment: Check available font names with doc.getFontList() , you can set any out of these using 
doc.setFont('times);

Answer (score 10):

Actually you can use

```
doc.addFont()
```

For example:

```
doc.addFont('ArialMS', 'Arial', 'normal');
doc.setFont('Arial');
doc.text(50,150,'Hello World');
```

Comment: it says `doc.addFont()` is not a function

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a standard font for jsPDF:

```
      doc.setFont("Helvetica");
      doc.setFontSize(10);
      doc.setTextColor(10);
```

The 14 standard PDF fonts are as follows:

```
Courier
Courier-Bold
Courier-BoldOblique
Courier-Oblique
Helvetica
Helvetica-Bold
Helvetica-BoldOblique
Helvetica-Oblique
Symbol
Times-Roman
Times-Bold
Time-Italic
Time-BoldItalic
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem
I have come up with the best solution
It is to use the latest version of the library
With jspdf.debug.js file usage
You'll find them here:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jspdf