# How to add a Custom Font to Dynamic data in PDF document by using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've tried to convert dynamic webpage to PDF by using jsPDF it worked for me and now I wants to change the font family of PDF by using jsPDF. Is there any option. Please let me know. Thanks!

Below my code

```
 <div id="#preview-details">dynamic data goes here..</div>
<button id="downloadPDF">Print</button>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                $('#downloadPDF').click(function () {
                    doc.fromHTML($('#preview-details').html(), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    });
                    doc.save('pdfdoc.pdf');
                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsPDF cannot set font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232813/jspdf-cannot-set-font-family)

Comment: This works for static date, but how to apply it for dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you have to download the font as a ttf format, then you need to add it into your code like the following code:

```
  // add custom font to file
  doc.addFont("ConsolasHex.ttf", "ConsolasHex", "Bold");
  doc.setFont("ConsolasHex","Bold");
  doc.setFontSize(12);
```

The page in this URL has explain it [enter link description here](https://www.devlinpeck.com/tutorials/jspdf-custom-font)